# Add UITableView to UITableViewCell Dynamically

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I wanna add a `UITableView` to `UITableViewCell` dynamically, when i click on the `UITableViewCell`, it will change it's height and display a `UITableView` inside it, and when i click on the `UITableViewCell` again, it will hide the `UITableView`.

To do that, i did the following:

1. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` with a nib file.
2. Load it to the main `UITableView` with adjusting the information i wanna display it before expanding it.
3. Implement the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to handel the selected `UITableViewCell`.
4. Initiate the second `UITableView` (it's a `UITableViewController`, created it with a nib file), resize the selected `UITableViewCell` to fit the new size (expand it's size).
5. Adding the `UITableView` using `[selectedCell.contentView addSubview:desc.view];`
6. Reload the main `UITableView`.

BUT, it didn't work, all i've got is an empty space with a correct size. i've used `[tableView addSubview:desc.view];` but it's add the `UITableView` inside the main `UITableView`, not inside the selected cell.

Note: the added `UITableView` is not scrollable and when i click on one of it's cell it will navigate me to another view.

Any hint will be appreciated.
thx in advance.

Comment: Have you implemented your datasource and delegate methods for the new tableView?

Comment: Yes, i've implemented the datasource and delegate methods, note that if the new uitableview was added to the main uitableview, it's shows correctly and with it's cell, but if i add the new uitableview to the selected cell, it won't show.

Comment: It looks like you are using a UITableViewController for the child tableview. If that is the case, stop doing that because you can only use on view controller at a time. You don't need a UITableViewController to use UITableView. Just use the view, not the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like sosborn said, i used a `UITableView` instead of `UITableViewController` and added the new table view in

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

cause i was calling the `[tableView reloadData]` every time the user select a cell.

Comment: Hi.. sorry i couldnt get your answer. am a beginner. I m trying to do the same thing which u ve done. Ve u created separate UIView and mapped it in to UITableviewCell in your 5th step?

Comment: Actually, I've created a new .h & .m files, connect them with an empty xib file and make the superclass for them `UITableView`. I've implemented the adding code in the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` that will be executed depend on boolean, the boolean will change in the `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` and at the end of this method, i've called `[tableView reloadData];`.